# UPDATE table id and its constraints MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, constraints

I Have a Database in mysql, i have a principal table that use a column name cedula VARCHAR (50), the column have characters, but i want to change it with a consecutive number. I tried with this:

```
SET @a:=1;
UPDATE bdpiiad2.tpersona 
SET cedula=(CONVERT(@a:=@a+1, CHAR(50)))
```

But i have 2 problems, first doesn't change, and second I'm not sure if change the other ids in the others tables that have a reference.

Comment: That's a wrong `convert` syntax. You can try like `SET cedula=(CAST(@a:=@a+1 as CHAR(50)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this

```
SET @a:=1;
UPDATE bdpiiad2.tpersona 
SET cedula=(CAST(@a:=@a+1 as CHAR));
```

to update all you need to create a procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `bdpiiad2`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bdpiiad2.`up`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `up`()
BEGIN
DECLARE max_cnt INT;
DECLARE cnt INT;
SET cnt=1;
UPDATE bdpiiad2.tpersona SET cedula='0';
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO max_cnt FROM bdpiiad2.tpersona;

WHILE cnt<=max_cnt DO
  UPDATE bdpiiad2.tpersona 
    SET cedula=(CAST(cnt AS CHAR))
    WHERE cedula='0' LIMIT 1;
  SET cnt=cnt+1;
END WHILE; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and then call it like this

```
CALL bdpiiad2.up();
```